# Why innerText does work for invisible elements? It should not

Tags: javascript

> - `textContent` gets the content of *all* elements, including
>   `<script>` and `<style>` elements.  In contrast, `innerText` only
>   shows "human-readable" elements.
> - `textContent` returns every element in the node.  In contrast,
>   `innerText` is aware of styling and won't return the text of
>   "hidden" elements.
>
> - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext

So it seems that `innerText` should ignore invisible elements, but acutally it doesn't. Why? It seems I misunderstood something.

Example 1

```js
const style = document.querySelector('style');

style.textContent = 'p { color: red; }'; // works
style.innerText = 'p { color: red; }';   // works. But why?

console.log(style.textContent); // works
console.log(style.innerText);   // works. But why?
```

```css
html { font-family: sans-serif; }
```

```html
<p>foo</p>
```

Example 2

```js
const invisibleDiv = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(invisibleDiv.innerText); // works. But why?
```

```html
<div style="display: none;">
  invisible div
</div>
```

Comment: Why does your second example have HTML in the CSS block?

Comment: And your first snippet has HTML in the CSS block, and CSS in the HTML block.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, fixed. This is because it's currently night where I live ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference only applies to elements that are nested within the element, not the element's text itself.

```js
console.log("outer.textContent:", outer.textContent);
console.log("outer.innerText:", outer.innerText);
console.log("inner.textContent:", inner.textContent);
console.log("inner.innerText:", inner.innerText);
```

```html
<div id="outer">This is visible <span id="inner" style="display: none;">This is invisible</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the element is still in the DOM **at the point in time JavaScript references it**.

To force the alert to fail, you need to remove the element with something like [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove), and **then** (attempt to) reference it.

As you can see in the following, even a Promise's resolution still retains the existing `.innerText`, as the reference was made before the element was updated. You explicitly need to update the reference:

```js
let invisibleDiv = document.getElementById('alert');
const resolvedProm = Promise.resolve(invisibleDiv.remove());

let thenProm = resolvedProm.then(value => {
  console.log(invisibleDiv.innerText); // Still exists
  invisibleDiv = document.getElementById('alert');
  console.log(invisibleDiv); // No longer exists
  return value;
});
```

```html
<div id="alert">invisible div</div>
```

Comment: he doesn't want it to fail, he just expects the `textContent` to be empty because it doesn't include invisible elements.

Comment: What is `Promise.resolve(invisibleDiv.remove())` supposed to do? `remove()` doesn't return anything, so what is the promise supposed to resolve to?

Comment: It seems I wasn't clear enough when asked my question. Sorry about this. Thanks anyway.